# What is $(OS) in a Makefile conditional?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Coming from https://gist.github.com/sighingnow/deee806603ec9274fd47#file-makefile-L6, the below works:

```
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
    IS_WINDOWS = 1
else
    IS_WINDOWS = 0
endif
```

This `$(OS)` in a conditional, I can't find docs on it anywhere. What is the story with `$(OS)`, and can anyone provide docs on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OS` environment variable is available on Windows systems; see e.g. [this list of Windows environment variables](https://pureinfotech.com/list-environment-variables-windows-10/).

This conditional...

```
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
```

...is checking if make is running on Windows by looking at the value of the `OS` environment variable. If it is equal to `Windows_NT`, make sets `IS_WINDOWS=1`.

Otherwise, make sets `IS_WINDOWS=0`.